# calculate the content of a variable

Tags: python, string, loops, variables, calculation

I'm learning python, and I have encountered a problem.

```
for i in input:
    operator = i.split()[0]
    number1 = i.split()[1]
    number2 = i.split()[2]
    equation = (number1 + ' ' +  operator + ' ' + number2)
```

This code is supposed to calculate a randomly generated input, for example:

`+  9   16`
this one wants me to print the result of 9 + 16

so I made code which converts the input into an equation but i have no idea how do tell the code to calculate it.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop:

```
a = input()
operator = a.split()[0]
number1 = a.split()[1]
number2 = a.split()[2]
equation = (number1 + ' ' +  operator + ' ' + number2)
print(equation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to get the whole sentence. Just an input would work since split() works for splitting a string by the given parameter. Just use an a = input().

Answer (score 0):

```
x = '+ 9 16'
operator, number1, number2 = x.split()
result  = eval(number1 + ' ' +  operator + ' ' + number2) #ugly
print(result)
```

In your case your can try

```
print(eval(equation)) #ugly
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression is a **prefix** expression, where the operator is the first followed by operands. `+ 9 16` is a simple expression because here you have just one operator i.e. `+` and two operands `9` and `16`.

```
def evaluate(num1, num2, operator):
    # returns the result after evaluating the expression
    if operator == '+': 
        return(num1 + num2) 

    elif operator == '-': 
        return(num1 - num2) 

    elif operator == '*': 
        return(num1 * num2) 

    elif operator == '/': 
        return(num1 / num2)


a = str(input())
# a = "+ 9 16"

temp = None
operator = ""

for i in a.split():
    # a.split() is a list
    if i.isdigit():
        # isdigit() returns true if i is a number
        if not temp:
            # this is our first operand
            temp = int(i) 
        else:
            # this is our second operand
            print(evaluate(temp, int(i), operator))
    else:
        # this is our operator
        operator = i
```

To evaluate a more complex prefix expression, we generally use a *stack*. To learn more about evaluating a complex prefix expression refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/evaluation-prefix-expressions/).